# JetPack Compose: Glitch UI, nested LazyRows with pagination

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-paging, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have LazyColumn with nested LazyRow lists.
Each row use `Flow<PaginData<UiObj>>` for showing data.

```
LazyColumn() {
            items(
                    items = showcaseRefList,
                    key = { it.urn },
                    contentType = { "showcaseRow" }
                ) {
                      val showcaseRowViewModel: ShowcaseRowViewModel =
                                koinViewModel(key = it.urn) {
                                    parametersOf(
                                        it.urn,
                                        it.type.nameType
                                    )
                                }

                            ShowcaseRow(
                                uiModelShowcasePageItem = it,
                                itemFlow = showcaseRowViewModel.pagerFlow,
                                onShowcaseItemClick = { }
                            )
                }
        }
```

PaginData i get using `Pager` with `RemoteMediator` and `PagingSource` from room.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
    val pagerFlow = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 20,
            initialLoadSize = 1,
            prefetchDistance = 5
        ),
        remoteMediator = remoteMediator,
        pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
    ).flow
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

pagingSourceFactory i got from room

```
@Query("select * from DbModelShowcaseBaseItem where parentUrn = :urn order by `order`")
    abstract fun getShowcaseItemsByUrnPagingSource(urn: String): PagingSource<Int, DbModelShowcaseItem>
```

When i start scroll first row and remoteMediator get api request and save data in room, all pagingSource call invalidate callback and i have glitch with blinkin items.
[Glitch on lazyRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcebB.gif)

`Flow<PaginData>` use `.cahceIn` with `viewModelScope` (each row have separate viewModel)
How islolate all this invalidation?

If i use `.disinctUntilChange`. its not working becase room always generate new `PagingSource` object in factory

Comment: Any updates about this? I have the same issue in all my LazyGrids.